# How to make the linebreak in conteditable div be posted as a new line?

Tags: javascript, php, html

In  contenteditable div, The line-break made by pressing the  enter key is indeed shown as a new line in this div. But when the value of the div being posted and fetched, the line break doesn't show up. I think by default it is captured as an empty string when posting to database and fetch out. I wondered what is the most common way to make it posted and fetched as a line break?

Comment: by _"posted and fetched"_ do you mean being displayed as html, or being displayed in a textarea?

Comment: the example given is a simple example of append but it demonstrates the use of the line break using \n

Comment: @PatrickEvans I mean being displayed as html.

Comment: the textarea does display a new line, but when the value is posted or fetched, the line break doesn't exist.

Comment: the nl2br() works with textarea, but not for contenteditable div

Answer (score 0):

Pass your text through [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) before displaying it. It will transform new line breaks into `<br>` tags.

```
$value = nl2br("Your \ndata");
?>
<div><?php echo $value;?></div>
```

Comment: It works with textarea, but not for contenteditable div